# How to update Bootcamp video card drivers on MacBook Pro 16" with Radeon Pro 5500M

Tags: bootcamp, windows, video, driver

I'm am unable to install the latest Radeon Pro 5500M drivers from the AMD site onto my MBP 16 in Bootcamp. The driver installer says it cannot find an AMD video card. From what I've read, it seems we have to wait for official Windows Bootcamp drivers to be updated via Apple releases, but before I accept that, I thought see if anyone else was able to update the drivers in Bootcamp (Windows 10).

Is there a way to install the latest gaming drivers in Windows Bootcamp for the new MBP 16 Radeon Pro 5500M display adapter?

Here's the driver I'm trying to install (64-bit Windows 10 version):

https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-5500-series/amd-radeon-rx-5500-series/amd-radeon-rx-5500m

Even though this appears to be the correct driver, it does not recognize the video adapter.

Comment: You might be an expert on it but just thought to ask you. once you are in the Windows from your MBP, have you try to download the 5500M windows 10 64bit driver. Didn't that help?

Comment: @Udhy yes, please see my updated question.